# Compiling nginx and php

Tags: nginx, php, security, performance

Im about to set up a basic web server based on ubuntu server 14.04 x64 with an online shop section, the server will also consist mysql, mail, and maybe other servers as well until it runs smoothly.

1. What are the total arguments that I can use to compile (./configure) NGINX from source? I read the whole NGINX documentation but it doesnt list all the arguments. I`m worrying about arguments like "--with-ipv6" or "--with-file-aio", NGINX doesnt list all the possibilities anywhere.
   Another thing that I guess I have to use the file aio argument in the configure command if I want to use it, why? file aio is part of the NGINX http core module which I guess can't be excluded from the compilation, do I need to compile any other (set of?) directives separately as well?
   Some modules cant be excluded during compilation eg: "--without-http_proxy_module", shall i remove them after compilation or its best to leave them alone?

My configure command looks like this so far: `./configure --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-ipv6 --with-http_auth_request_module --without-http_autoindex_module --without-http_charset_module --without-http_empty_gif_module --without-http_fastcgi_module --without-http_geo_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --without-http_memcached_module --with-http_mp4_module --without-http_proxy_module --without-http_referer_module --without-http_rewrite_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_spdy_module --without-http_split_clients_module --without-http_ssi_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --without-http_uwsgi_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --without-mail_pop3_module --add-module=/nginx/nginx-1.7.10/nginx-http-sysguard --add-module=/home/zsolt/ngx-third-party-modules/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.3-beta`

2. PHP or NGINX + modules?
   which one is faster, which using less resources and, which one is more secure  if i would use them for: manipulating mysql databases, server side includes, restricting access by IP address, redirects, and so on...

I`ve been searching in google for these answers with no luck, maybe I have used the wrong keywords or no one was ever wondering about these questions, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Actually it does. `./configure --help`
2. I would not worry about `aio` in the beginning. I would experiment with it while fine-tuning the server. Anyway you should compile it in.
3. nginx `proxy` module is one of the essential modules, you should really keep it in.
4. PHP is for parsing PHP script languages, and nginx is the web-server that can work with PHP via `fcgi` interface. You last question is nonsense. *Nile alligator or 122hp diesel engine, - who's faster ?*

Follow-up: pagespeed is bad, unless you have unlimited CPU resources. It's always better to optimize the site *before* serving it, than doing it on the fly - especially when using such tweaky automagical tricks like page speed - *optimize the whole thing for me, I just don't want to worry about the process*. Pagespeed really minimizes the bandwidth for the client, but the cost is really high.